# Pseudobipolar signal example - Analog Devices AD7682

Tags: adc, signal, datasheet, education

What is a pseudobipolar signal? I read this word in the datasheet below:

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7682_7689.pdf

Can you show me an example with a plot please?
Online I found only the definition of pseudo-differential unipolar and other definitions:

http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/product-selector-card/2PB_sarinputtypesfb.pdf

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It helps offset sig gnd from ADC ground using eg Vcc/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Pseudo Bipolar signal is just a bipolar signal with a non-zero voltage at which the signal is considered to have zero magnitude.  A "true" bipolar signal has 0V as the zero magnitude voltage.

Pseudo Bipolar allows you to use a positive reference voltage and voltage range at the ADC input and generate positive and negative output values, with respect to the reference voltage.  This saves having to use a bipolar power supply.

You already have a plot of pseudo bipolar in your second reference.  It is just named slightly differently.  In this case, the zero magnitude voltage is 2.5V.

[image]

Comment: Hello @crj11, in the datasheet there is "pseudobipolar" without the word differential. Is there a pseudobipolar not differential input?

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi I agree that the terminology is confusing.  My take on the difference between differential and non differential is that in the non-differential case, you assume that the reference input is fixed and the other input varies.  In the differential case, both inputs vary, but have a non-zero common mode voltage.

Comment: sorry for the hassle. If I have a single-ended (=non differential) input, the signal can be unipolar or bipolar. Pseudobipolar is difficult to think about.

Comment: only now I understood what you said me...Thank you for your good explanation.